# Networking connectivity issue with fiber optics and two routers

Tags: networking, nat, bridge-router

Internet access is at our office and we ran fiber optics with media convertors to our shop.

All three computers are Windows 10, 2 in the office one at the shop.

The internet is Wireless without an accessible physically accesible modem but you can log on to it. It says "xplore".

cable comes out of there to a switch which then distributes to the office Network and also out the fiber optics media converter to the shops linksys 1200ac router

Internet access and WiFi all work at both locations.

From the shop I can access both office computers. However from the office I can't access the shop computer

Apparently this is a double NAT situation. I put the shop router in bridge mode and could see the office computer. Unfortunately WiFi stopped working which is untenable and you can no longer logon to the router. Disabling DHCP is also not an option. I'm going to try bringing the fibre into a lan port instead of the WLAN port today at the shop

How can I get this network running properly?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to add specifics so the community can better help you solve this: What is the make/model of the modem?  What is the make/model of the router? What kind of PCs are attempting to connect to this network? Windows? macOS? What versions? Please edit your question to add this info so we can better help you.

Comment: check the ip numbers on both nets and use "route add" command to merge them

Comment: Thank you Giacomo1968 that was actually really stupid I should have included that information originally I have updated the post. Petepf I will do some reading on this route add command and see how it goes thanks you guys for your input